# How can I load textures from a spritesheet in Java using Slick-Utils?

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm creating a game using LWJGL and Slick Utils. I'm trying to load an animated texture as a set of frames contained in a single PNG image.

I have tried to figure out how to get subimages using Slick, but so far all I've been able to find on the subject is a way to do it outside of Slick using BufferedImages. I'd like to know if there is a way to do this using the Slick Utils library, since all of my image loading code in my project so far has been using Slick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, Slick provides a way to do this. If you look at `org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet.initImpl()` and later `org.newdawn.slick.SpriteSheet.getSprite()`, you will notice how `org.newdawn.slick.Image.getSubImage()` can be used to quickly extract specific portions of an existing image.

**SpriteSheet.java**

```java
protected void initImpl() {
    if (subImages != null) {
        return;
    }

    int tilesAcross = ((getWidth()-(margin*2) - tw) / (tw + spacing)) + 1;
    int tilesDown = ((getHeight()-(margin*2) - th) / (th + spacing)) + 1; 
    if ((getHeight() - th) % (th+spacing) != 0) {
        tilesDown++;
    }

    subImages = new Image[tilesAcross][tilesDown];
    for (int x=0;x<tilesAcross;x++) {
        for (int y=0;y<tilesDown;y++) {
            //extract parts of the main image and store them in an array as sprites
            subImages[x][y] = getSprite(x,y);
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Get a sprite at a particular cell on the sprite sheet
 * 
 * @param x The x position of the cell on the sprite sheet
 * @param y The y position of the cell on the sprite sheet
 * @return The single image from the sprite sheet
 */
public Image getSprite(int x, int y) {
    target.init();
    initImpl();

    if ((x < 0) || (x >= subImages.length)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SubImage out of sheet bounds: "+x+","+y);
    }
    if ((y < 0) || (y >= subImages[0].length)) {
        throw new RuntimeException("SubImage out of sheet bounds: "+x+","+y);
    }
    //Call Image.getSubImage() to get a portion of the image
    return target.getSubImage(x*(tw+spacing) + margin, y*(th+spacing) + margin,tw,th); 
}
```

You should be able to use that as reference. I remember having fully ported the Tiled renderer bundled with Slick to Java2D once, using the old good PixelGrabber to extract sprites.

And if you decide to use `SpriteSheet`, you can find an example of use in `org.newdawn.slick.tiled.Layer.render()`:

**Layer.java**

```java
public void render(int x, int y, int sx, int sy, int width, int ty,
        boolean lineByLine, int mapTileWidth, int mapTileHeight) {
    for (int tileset = 0; tileset < map.getTileSetCount(); tileset++) {
        TileSet set = null;

        for (int tx = 0; tx < width; tx++) {
            if ((sx + tx < 0) || (sy + ty < 0)) {
                continue;
            }
            if ((sx + tx >= this.width) || (sy + ty >= this.height)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (data[sx + tx][sy + ty][0] == tileset) {
                if (set == null) {
                    set = map.getTileSet(tileset);
                    set.tiles.startUse();
                }

                int sheetX = set.getTileX(data[sx + tx][sy + ty][1]);
                int sheetY = set.getTileY(data[sx + tx][sy + ty][1]);

                int tileOffsetY = set.tileHeight - mapTileHeight;

                //Call SpriteSheet.renderInUse() to render the sprite cached at slot [sheetX, sheetY]
                set.tiles.renderInUse(x + (tx * mapTileWidth), y
                        + (ty * mapTileHeight) - tileOffsetY, sheetX,
                        sheetY);
            }
        }

        if (lineByLine) {
            if (set != null) {
                set.tiles.endUse();
                set = null;
            }
            map.renderedLine(ty, ty + sy, index);
        }

        if (set != null) {
            set.tiles.endUse();
        }
    }
}
```

**SpriteSheet.java**

```java
public void renderInUse(int x,int y,int sx,int sy) {
    //Draw the selected sprite at (x,y), using the width/height defined for this SpriteSheet
    subImages[sx][sy].drawEmbedded(x, y, tw, th);
}
```

Hope this helps you.